# Trying to create a shortcut in batch for server

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, shortcut

Trying to create a shortcut in batch using a VBScript. I need to change the properties of the path to allow it to run in no-graphics mode.

```
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set shortcut = oWS.CreateShortcut("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\unturned.exe -batchmode -nographics +secureserver/TheServer.lnk") >> %SCRIPT%
echo shortcut.TargetPath = "D:\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo shortcut.Save >> %SCRIPT%


cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

It can't save.

Comment: What do you mean "can't save"? The shortcut properties dialog won't close? The batch file can't write to the VBS output? Or what?

Comment: When i run the program it says WshShortcut.save: unable to save shortcut. I know it has to do with the -batchmode and other things on the end because those are extras that do actually point to the file itself. So is there a way to add those extras on.

Comment: I answered it myself thanks for the help though. I had to move the -batchmode and other things to the target path instead of the name

Answer (score 0):

This should did the trick :

```
@echo off
Set vbsfile=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%.vbs
Set MyFile=D:\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe
Set ShorcutName=Unturned
(
echo Call Shortcut("%MyFile%","%ShorcutName%"^)
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************^)
echo Sub Shortcut(CheminApplication,Nom^)
echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
echo    MyTab = Split(CheminApplication,"\"^)
echo    If Nom = "" Then
echo    Nom = MyTab(UBound(MyTab^)^)
echo    End if
echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Nom ^& ".lnk"^)
echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(CheminApplication^)
echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "Winver.exe,0"
echo    objShortCut.Save
echo End Sub
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
echo ^'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
echo Function DblQuote(Str^)
echo    DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr(34^)
echo End Function
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
) > %vbsfile%
Start /Wait %vbsfile%
Del %vbsfile%
::****************************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%

echo Set shortcut = oWS.CreateShortcut("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\unturned.exe.lnk") >> %SCRIPT%

echo shortcut.TargetPath = "D:\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe -batchmode -nographics +secureserver/TheServer" >> %SCRIPT%

echo shortcut.Save >> %SCRIPT%


cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```